# Is there a package that would allow me to colorize non-alphanumeric characters (the symbols)?

Tags: package, highlighting

By non-alphanumeric characters, it includes the period, comma, colon, semi-colon, plus/minus sign, star sign, slashes, percentage sign, and any other that are normally used for mathematical operators or syntactical purposes such as for denoting membership of a C++ or a python class. I am imagining something similar to the rainbow delimiters package but preferable won't interfere with it because I have it already installed.

Comment: Specify more carefully what you want. Do you want to highlight, say, `+` within a symbol name, e.g., `foo+bar`, or just on its own, e.g. `+`, or just in combination with itself or other such chars, e.g., `+-++---`? And is this on-demand highlighting or font-locking?

Comment: @Drew wherever the symbol appears outside string expressions.

Comment: Specify everything in the *question*. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is to use `highlight-regexp`; read its docstring to see how to use it. However, using it, I don't know an easy way to exclude characters in strings (but that might not be that important).

You could try the following example:

`M-:` `(highlight-regexp "[^[:alnum:] \n]" 'isearch-fail)`

which also excludes spaces and newlines from getting highlighted.